# input field can have only one character and 8 numbers

Tags: html, jquery

i am trying to set, if input field can have 8 digits and one letter at the end,
Example: 25639154R

My code:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paycheck" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

$( "input" ).attr("pattern", '^[A-z]{1}||^[0-9]{8}').prop('required', true)
```

it's working for any 8 numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$( "input" ).attr("pattern", '^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$').prop('required', true)
```

This will require the last character to be uppercase. You can add `a-z` inside the character group to allow for case insensitive characters too.